# Prove that a function is both differentiable and continous at a point $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose $f$ is differentialble on $(a,b)$, except possibly at $x_0 \in (a,b)$ an is continous on $[a,b]$; assume $ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f´(x)$ exists. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f´$ is continous at $x_0$.

My attempt:

If we have that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then we are done, but if it is not the case then we proceed as follows.

Since $ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f´(x)$ exists, let´s call it $L$, we have that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that $|x-x_0|\Rightarrow|f´(x)-L|< \epsilon $

Now, we know that $f$ is continous on $[a,b]$, then in particular is continous in $[x_0,x]$ an differentiable there, then by the MVT we have that exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that:

$$f´(c)= \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ for $a<x_0<x<b$.

**But I get stuck there because I dont know how to complete the prove using the above facts, I dont know how to conect them Can you help to prove this? Thank you I need your help :)**

**I am back Can you help me please?, thank you :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that by definition of the derivative 
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Therefore 
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\}$$
By the assumption of your problem the "inside" limit exists for all $x=x_0\pm\epsilon$ and every $\epsilon>0$. Also the problem states that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)$ exists therefore
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\}=\lim_{h\to 0}\{\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=f'(x_0)$$
Hence 
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)=f'(x_0)$$
so $f$ is differentiable at $x=x_0$. Also because $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)=f'(x_0)$ then $f'(x)$ is continous at $x=x_0$.

Comment: Thank you :) @Adrian And with this are We done?

Comment: @user162343: if a function is differentiable at a given point then it is also continous at that point.

Comment: Yes that is right then this proofs the claim  isnt? :)

Comment: the things in {} are sequences ?

Comment: @user162343: you can think of the thing inside the paranthesis as a sequence of a ratio that depends on $h$ and $h$ becomes arbitrarily small.

Comment: oh no they are only limits :), but why can you switch the limit in the step: limx→x0{limh→0f(x+h)−f(x)h}=limh→0{limx→x0f(x+h)−f(x)h}=limh→0f(x0+h)−f(x0)h=f′(x0)?

Comment: Why do we didn`t need to use the Mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes you are correct the expression inside brackets is a limit, but think of it as a limit of a sequence that depends on $h$ and $h$ becomes smaller and smaller. Because the limit of the expression inside exists for all $x$ except possibly at $x=x_0$ and the limit outside exists at $x=x_0$ then you can justify the interchange of limits.

Comment: Why do we didn`t need to use the Mean value theorem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18006/discussion-between-adrian-and-user162343).

Comment: ok thank you a lot and really :) you were the only one who helped
Oh I forget to ask you something @Adrian, with the proof on the post you also prove that f ' is continous at x_0 isnt?
I think you did not prove that :( jajaja that is miss there :)
I got confused in that part :) jajaja
we just forget that fact :) I only need to be sure that you prove that there in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

What we need to show is that 
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
exists and is equal to 
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} f'(x);$$
this would make $f$ differentiable and $f'$ continuous at $x_0$.  But as you said, the thing
$$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
is equal to $f'(c)$ for some $c$ that approaches $x_0$ as $x$ does.

Comment: I dont undestand your answer very well can you expalin it please :)

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Well I am sorry because of the delay but, my question is that Am I right? or how can I use your answer to solve my problem?, thank you :)

Comment: Please I really need your help :), I think there is happening something in my question that no one answers, and I really need the help thank you :)