# The second derivative of $f^{-1}$ and another question. :)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are twice differentiable functions. Derive a formula for $(f^{-1})''$.

My attempt:

We have that by the inverse function theorem that:

$(f^{-1}(x))'=(f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(x)))'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$

then

$(f^{-1}(x))''=(\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))})'$

therefore by the division rule:

$(\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))})'= \frac{(1)'·(f'(f^{-1}(x)))-(f'(f^{-1}(x)))'·(1)}{(f'(f^{-1}(x))^{2}}$

then by the chain Rule we have :

$(f'(f^{-1}(x)))'=f''(f^{-1}(x))·(f^{-1}(x))'$

therefore:

$(f^{-1}(x))''=-\frac{f''(f^{-1}(x))·(f^{-1}(x))'}{(f'(f^{-1}(x))^{2}}$

**Am I right in the derivative, if not how can I fix it ? thank you, and Can you help me with this question please:**

[Prove that a function is both differentiable and continous at a point $x_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980454/prove-that-a-function-is-both-differentiable-and-continous-at-a-point-x-0)

**Please I really need your help :), I think there is happening something in my question that no one answers, and I really need the help thank you :)** 
**Is important thank you :)**

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

$$\begin{align} f^{-1}(f(x)) &= x \\ (f^{-1})'(f(x)) \ f'(x) &= 1 \\ (f^{-1})''(f(x)) \ (f'(x))^2 + (f^{-1})'(f(x)) \ f''(x) &= 0 \\ (f^{-1})''(f(x)) &= -\frac{(f^{-1})'(f(x)) \ f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2} \\ (f^{-1})''(f(x)) &= -\frac{f''(x)}{(f'(x))^3}\end{align}$$

whenever everything makes sense and is well-defined.

Comment: Thank you and can you help me with the other question please :)

Comment: Please I really need your help :), I think there is happening something in my question that no one answers, and I really need the help thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track, but you should take one more step.  Once you get

$$(f^{-1}(x))''=-\frac{f''(f^{-1}(x))·(f^{-1}(x))'}{(f'(f^{-1}(x))^{2}},$$

use the formula for the derivative of the inverse function once again

$$(f^{-1}(x))'= \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$

and after the substitution, get

$$\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)''=-\frac{f''(f^{-1}(x))}{\left(f'(f^{-1}(x)\right)^{3}}.$$

Comment: Thank you and can you help me with the other question please :)

Comment: Please I really need your help :), I think there is happening something in my question that no one answers, and I really need the help thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

$$f^{-1}(f(x))=x\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x))=1\Rightarrow (f^{-1})'\cdot f'(x)=1\Rightarrow (f^{-1})'=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$$
Differentiate both sides of the last expression wrt $x$ again to get:
$$(f^{-1})''\cdot f'(x)=-\frac{f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2}\Rightarrow (f^{-1})''=-\frac{f''(x)}{(f'(x))^3}$$

Comment: That can't be right.

Comment: @UserX:Why is that?

Comment: Second equality, chain rule. $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} f^{-1}(f(x))=(f^{-1})' (f(x))\cdot f'(x)$$

Comment: Is that wrong in the @UserX `s aswer or mine ? and why ?

Comment: Can you help me with the other question too please :) thank you :)

Comment: @UserX: these are equivalent $(f^{-1})'=f'^{-1}(f(x))$

Comment: Really? I thought $(f^{-1})'$ implied $(f^{-1})'(x)$

Comment: @UserX: Anyways I hope it is clear now what I meant in my solution.

Comment: Then I am right using the arguments of my post and @AlexanderBelopolsky `s or @IvoTerek`s isnt ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980454/prove-that-a-function-is-both-differentiable-and-continous-at-a-point-x-0 :)